# Сравнение двух списков поэлементно

Tags: python, python-3.x

мне нужно сравнить два списка на общие элементы массивов, так чтобы при совпадении одного элемента с другим сравнение продолжилось, а при совпадении двух и более элементов списков сравнение прекратилось.
На скриншоте представлен не верный ответ count и выведены все списки которые были созданы для сравнения с исходником + сам исходный список.
При a=13 и b=5 3 1 3 5 2 5 3 1 3 5 2 5 верный ответ должен быть 6.

```
a = int(input("Количество чисел которое назвал ведущий: ")) 
b = list(map(int, input("Числа на которые указывала стрелка в процессе вращения барабана").split()))
count = 0
c = b[0:2]
d = b[1:a]
if a % 2 == 1:
   del b[-1]
for i in b:
   c == d
while False:
    count += 1
print(count)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А собственно какие ДВА списка вы сравниваете между собой в своем коде?

Comment: Я сравниваю списки c и d

Comment: Про то, где вы их сравниваете  -  спрашивать не будут. Но попробуйте объяснить, что вы хотели сказать, записав эту конструкцию да еще и в цикле: "c == d"